# Является ли хорошей практикой использование RTTI в С++11 в целях сериализации?

Tags: c++, c++11, сериализация, rtti

Например, мне надо записать группу объектов в файл, для этого я должен использовать тот или иной представитель класса `NodeConstructor`. В общем виде я сделал функцию:

```
virtual NodeConstructor<Node> *NodeConstructor::nodeConstructor(const Node *child) const = 0;
```

которая должна сопоставить каждому объекту (по его классу) тот или иной `NodeConstructor` для записи его полей. В моем, частном, случае, я пока обхожусь без **RTTI**, так как у каждого подобекта есть так называемая "роль" (не буду останавливать что это, но интуитивно, думаю, понятно), которую я могу сопоставить соответствующий `NodeConstructor`. Но как быть в общем случае, когда таких "ролей" или любых других идентификаторов не будет?

Моя идея - использовать `typeid` для каждого объекта и их то и сопостовлять. Но **Старая Школа**, помнится, учила, что использование `RTTI` не является хорошей практикой, мол, жрет много ресурсов, надо отдельно включать опцию и вообще - признак плохого проектирования.

Что говорит на это **Новая Школа** C++11 и выше? Ведь, как я понимаю, использование `auto` уже подразумевает включенный  `RTTI`, а использование `auto` сейчас в C++1x считается хорошей практикой. Пожираемость ресурсов зависит от компилятора, судя по найденной мной информации. А для целей сериализации использовани `typeid` не плохое проектирование, а именно "just as planned". Хотел бы прочитать ваши возражения и суждения по этому поводу?

Comment: С чего это auto подразумевает RTTI?

Comment: @punchel нет? возможно я и ошибаюсь. Но является ли плохой практикой использование `typeid`? Этот вопрос меня интересует

Comment: @AlexF Да, комментарий о Boost Serialization очень похож на ответ на мой вопрос, спасибо! Похоже, я пытаюсь свелосипедить идеи этой библиотеки для своих нужд. Если оформите как ответ - приму

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost Serialization подразумевает использование RTTI. Так что использование RTTI для сериализации вполне нормально.

Что касается шаблонов, советую посмотреть `template specialization`. Это общепринятый способ решать проблему выбора шаблона в зависимости от типа параметра.

Comment: Ответ заслуживает от меня двойной полезности - за сам ответ + за наводку на `template specialization`, но, к сожалению, движок форума не позволяет. Поэтому прошу мимопроходила поставить еще дополнительный лайк от меня!